PHP API PLATFORM Multi Tenancy Doctrine DB
I am having issue with Multi Tenancy in PHP API PLATFORM when I am trying something like this with Wrapper Class:
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                wrapper_class: App\Doctrine\TenantConnection
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_HOST)%'
                port: 3306
                user: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_USER)%'
                password: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_PASSWORD)%'
                charset: UTF8MB4

class TenantConnection extends Connection
{
      public function __construct(array $params, $driver, $config)
      {
        $tenantId = $_SERVER['HTTP_TENANT_ID'] ?? null;
        $dbName = // get by $tenantId from json (simply)
        $params['dbname'] = $dbName; // dynamic change of DB Name

        try {
            parent::__construct($params, $driver);
        } catch(ConnectionException $e) {
            
        }
      }
}

When I running this locally it all works fine. But when I build dockefile to GKE its failing because the $_SERVER['HTTP_TENANT_ID'] is not defined (at some experiment, when I try to call controller which was returning $_SERVER['HTTP_TENANT_ID'] it was all fine and present).
Is there problem with Caddy/Franken on production? I thing its loading all container into cache so all http requests will be faster. But how can I modify my Multi Tenancy experiment to make that work? Or is it bad practice? I would like to avoid to have multiple backend where only change will be dbName (from env). Thanks for any help.

params should be private.
You have to initalize new connection
public function changeDatabase(Tenant $tenant): bool
{
    $params = $this->getParams();
    if ($params['dbname'] !== $tenant->getDatabaseParam()->getName()) {
        if ($this->isConnected()) {
            $this->close();
        }
        $params['url'] = "postgresql://" . $params['user'] . ":" . $params['password'] . "@" . $params['host'] . ":" . $params['port'] . "/" . $tenant->getDatabaseParam()->getName(
            );
        $params['dbname'] = $tenant->getDatabaseParam()->getName();
        parent::__construct(
            $params,
            $this->_driver,
            $this->_config,
            $this->_eventManager
        );
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
